# PhoneCallTask fails

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

This is a really simple task but somehow it fails...

```
private void TextBlock_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WasSwipe != true)
        {
            //JUST TO CHECK THAT CODE GETS HERE - RUNS PERFECT
            MessageBox.Show("");

            //FUNCTION
            var phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask
            {
                DisplayName = "Kunal Chowdhury",
                PhoneNumber = "0208795446322"
            };
            phoneCallTask.Show();
            //FAILS HERE, AFTER SHOW
        }
        else
        {
            WasSwipe = false;
        }
    }
```

When i want to show task it fails with this:

> **Message:** Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> **Source:** Microsoft.Phone
>
> **Stack-trace:**  at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask.NativeMethods.PhoneInitiateOutgoingPhoneCall_External(String
>   pDialString, String pDisplayName)
>
> at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask.PhoneDial(Object
>   phoneCallTask)
>
> at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>
> at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

**IN ADDITION:**

Email task works:

```
 EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

            emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
            emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
            emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
            emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
            emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";

            emailComposeTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably didn't specify following permission in your app [manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER
```